# wrong json format in swift

Tags: json, post, swift2, xcode7

I'm trying to send json object to server. The server expects object to be in this format:

```
{
"Lat": 10.33688590000001, 
"Name": "nameOfSomething", 
"Lng": 58.43135800000005
}
```

but the object that I'm getting after defining object is this:

```
[
"Lat": 10.33688590000001, 
"Name": nameOfSomething, //this is missing ""
"Lng": 58.43135800000005
]
```

the code that I'm using is this:

```
let jsonObject: [String: AnyObject] = [

    "Lat": lat,
    "Name": nameOfSender.text!,
    "Lng": lng
    ]


let jsonData = try! NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(jsonObject, options: .PrettyPrinted)
```

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: Try with no options `[]` instead of `.PrettyPrinted` for sending JSON to a server.

Comment: @Eric Aya - Didn't work. I think that error lies somewhere along the "let jsonObject: [String: AnyObject] = [" line where I define object

Comment: Are you really sending it to the server or are you stopping before because you *think* there is an issue? I don't see anything in your code that can cause an issue with a server (except pretty printed but you say this isn't the reason). Don't rely on what you see and send the JSON data not pretty printed - what happens? What is the error message?

Comment: @Eric Aya - server is giving me error in the likes that the data I'm sending him isn't properly formatted. I'm suspecting that's due to those [ ] in swift when I'm defining json object. The conventional way is that json object should be in { }. Am I correct with that?

Comment: You are correct but `NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject` *does* give you the correct format already. You can see this if you transform jsonData to a String again: `print(String(data: jsonData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)`

Comment: yes you are 100% correct. That the error must lie somewhere else.. Thx anyway for this great piece of information!

Answer (score 0):

```
 Please Look on this. it will give you correct answer.  
  /// Use this method to get JSON string from Dictionary.
  ///
  ///
  /// - returns: `String` for Dictionary
  func getJSONStringForDictionary(dict:[String:AnyObject]) -> String {
    do {
      let jsonData = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(dict, options: [])
      if let jsonString = NSString(data: jsonData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) as? String {
        return jsonString
      }
      // here "jsonData" is the dictionary encoded in JSON data
    } catch let error as NSError {
      print(error)
    }
    return ""
  }


/* calling */


let json = self.getJSONStringForDictionary(jsonObject)


  print(json)
//{
  "Lat" : 10.33688590000001,
  "Name" : "nameOfSomething",
  "Lng" : 58.43135800000005
}
```